# Emailing to new top-level domains (TLDs) in django

Tags: django, email-validation

I need to support email addresses like **joe@netherworld.enterprises** (one of the newly approved TLDs). My version of django is 1.4.5, and python is 2.7

My model looks like so:

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, blank=False)
```

The problem is that the validator 'EmailField' is rejecting 'enterprises', I assume because it's too long, and doesn't end with .com or similar. (**.enterprises** is now a valid Top-Level Domain.)

How can I tell the validator to accept that domain? (And preferably others like it.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you subclass [`EmailField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.5/django/forms/fields.py#L472) and substitute its set of `default_validators` with a custom validator that also supports the new top-level TLDs.

The default validator is `django.core.validators.validate_email` which in turn points to an instance of [`EmailValidator`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.5/django/core/validators.py#L142), which obviously you will have to subclass as well, and supply an instance of this subclass as the only item in `default_validators` attribute of your `EmailField` subclass.

You may want to have a look at the newer implementations of [`EmailValidator`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py) which not only supports TLDs ranging form 2 to 63 characters in length, but also a [`whitelist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.EmailValidator.whitelist) parameter that allows you to inject at custom list of valid domains.

Or, off course, if you prefer just upgrade to a newer Django version. I'm not sure exactly when the support for longer TLDs was added, but I'm sure you could figure that out by looking at the release logs or browsing the source.